# Why does a Django foreign key id __in query fail to match None?

Tags: django, django-models, django-3.2

When filtering a queryset on a nullable foreign key, I can filter by an ID value (`foo_id=123`) or by None (`foo_id=None`). However, if I attempt to filter by a list (`foo_id__in=[123, None]`) the `None` is ignored.

Why is this happening, and what is the best workaround for filtering on a foreign key using a list which includes None?

Example:

```py
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Bar(models.Model):
  foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                          blank=True, null=True)
```

```py
foo = Foo.objects.create(name='myfoo')
Bar.objects.create(foo=foo)
Bar.objects.create(foo=None)

Bar.objects.count()                                    # 2
Bar.objects.filter(foo_id=foo.id).count()              # 1
Bar.objects.filter(foo_id=None).count()                # 1
Bar.objects.filter(foo_id__in=[foo.id, None]).count()  # 1 - Expected 2!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key insight is that in SQL, `NULL` represents an unknown value, which cannot be compared using normal operators:

```
SELECT NULL = NULL;
-- => NULL
```

(This syntax does not work in all DB engines - for example, SQL Server - and in those you would have to write something like `SELECT CASE WHEN NULL = NULL THEN 't' ELSE 'f' END`, but the result is same: `NULL = NULL` evaluates as `NULL`, which is falsy.)

The reasoning is, for example, if you have two people whose last name you don't know, you'd mark them as `NULL` - and just because they are both `NULL`, you can't conclude that they have the same last name (just like you can't conclude they have a different one - you just don't know one way or the other).

So, a `NULL` is not equal to another `NULL`... but it's also not different than another `NULL`: `NULL <> NULL` also returns `NULL`. In fact, `NULL` infects all operators: `1 + NULL`, `1 < NULL`, `1 >= NULL`... all result in `NULL`. If you do anything with an unknown value, the result is an unknown value.

There is basically only one operator that avoids this infectious nature of `NULL`, and that is `IS NULL`:

```
SELECT NULL IS NULL;
-- => t
```

In the same vein as `x = NULL`, `x IN (NULL)` is also using the same equality comparison, which can never evaluate as true:

```
SELECT 2 IN (1, NULL);
-- => NULL
SELECT NULL IN (1, NULL);
-- => NULL
SELECT 1 IN (1, NULL);
-- => t

SELECT 2 NOT IN (1, NULL);
-- => NULL
SELECT NULL NOT IN (1, NULL);
-- => NULL
SELECT 1 NOT IN (1, NULL);
-- => t
```

Is `2` there? Maaaaybe; I have a value that I don't know what it is, so I can't say whether `2` is in there or not, because it just might match that unknown one. How about this other thing that I have no idea about? Beats me, might be `1`, or might be equal to the other unknown thing - or it might be something different altogether. How about `1`? Well, as to that, I can see `1` in there, regardless of what the unknown thing is or isn't.

So instead of plain `IN`, you have to check for `NULL` explicitly:

```
SELECT * WHERE foo_id IN (1, 2) OR foo_id IS NULL;
```

In django terms:

```
from django.db.models import Q
Bar.objects.filter(Q(foo_id=foo.id) | Q(foo_id__isnull=True)).count()
```

or if you have several values

```
Bar.objects.filter(Q(foo_id__in=[1, 2]) | Q(foo_id__isnull=True)).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the `None` in `foo_id__in=[123, None]` is ignored, but the best workaround I've come up with is the following:

```py
Bar.objects.filter(Q(foo_id=foo.id) | Q(foo_id=None)).count()
```